# C++ regex on partial data

Tags: c++, regex, search, boost, streaming

I have a callback function, which provides pointer to data and it's size. I don't know what size will be next time and which call will be the last. And I need to match incoming data with regex and save matches.
Something like that.

```
class data_filter
{
public:
    data_filter(const std::string& re)
        : re_(re)
    {}
public:
    // callback func. It will be called many times with data parts
    void process(const char* data, const size_t len) 
    {
        re_.match(data, len, m_); // if found match, add it to matches
    }

public:
    void print_matches()
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < m_.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << m_[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    some_cool_regex re_;
    cool_regex_matches m_;
};
```

If absolutely neccessary i can provide some fixed buffer for regex backtracking, but i would like to avoid it. 
I already had a brief look at `boost::regex` with `partial_match` option. As far as i understood from a first glance it can provide such functionality, but user should manually deal with temporary buffer.

So, should i stick with boost or there are some libraries that match my needs closer?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since, indeed, there could be a need for backtracking, your options for streaming are limited or non-existent.

Boost Spirit "solves" the same issue by using the `multi_pass_iterator<>` adapter around input iterators. The adapter is able to maintain a buffer of previously read data for backtracking, freeing it as soon as it is no longer required (e.g. due to an expectation point).

If you shared some details about "some cool regex" then I could probably show you how to do this.

**UPDATE** Just found this library: https://github.com/openresty/sregex

> **libsregex** - A non-backtracking regex engine library for large data streams

Comment: I don't know these details myself. Ideally it should be used as described in my example. Additionaly I can provide some data buffer (vector, array e.t.c.) for backtracking. And for regex strings themselves, there are no limits on them. Everything, that is valid regular expression.

Comment: Note I just found a library that might help: see update